# TypeError: Cannot read property ‘startsWith’ of undefined in MERN

Tags: mean-stack, mern

I am developing a MERN stack web application. But I cannot build the server due to these errors. If anyone knows how to solve these error. Help me out to solve this.

[image: Code of index.js file]

[image: Error Output]

Comment: Can you add the code where you are calling  `connectionStringHasValidScheme` function?

Comment: I have already attatched that. Check in upper screenshot.

Comment: Please post the code and error as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fix the variable name of URL in Config.env file and the error resolved! :)